# Aggregating multiple test cases from multiple modules to run in PyDev TestRunner

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev

What's the best way to aggregate test cases from multiple modules such that a single test run will execute them all and present the results in the PyDev UnitTest window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many choices in PyDev depending on what you want:

1. Right-click a folder and choose 'run as > Python unit-test' (will run all modules below the dir as unit-tests).
2. Right-click multiple python modules and choose 'run as > Python unit-test' (will load the tests for all those modules and run them).
3. Create a module which imports all the tests with a different name and select 'run as > Python unit-test' for that module.

i.e.:

```
from test_mod1 import Test as Test1
from test_mod2 import Test as Test2
```

Comment: Just to note, if it becomes big, you may want to auto-generate that with something as cog (http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import unittest
# add here some import paths
sys.path.append(r'..\..')


if True: #__name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        __file__
    except NameError:
        path = '.'
    else:
        path = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
    caseset = dict()
    def addSuite(suite):
        for case in suite:
            if isinstance(case, unittest.TestSuite):
                addSuite(case)
                continue
            key = case.id()
            if key in caseset:
##                print 'in:', type(case).__name__
                pass
            else:
##                print 'new:', type(case).__name__
                caseset[key] = case

    for filename in os.listdir(path): # could also be os.walk
        if filename.startswith('test_'):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            modname, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filepath) and ext.lower() in ('py', 'pyw'):
                mod = __import__(modname)
            else:
                try:
                    mod = __import__(modname)
                except ImportError:
                    ty, er, tb = sys.exc_info()
                    if tb.tb_next:
                        traceback.print_exception(ty, er, tb)
                    continue

            cases = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(mod)
            addSuite(cases)
    l = caseset.values()
    suite = unittest.TestSuite(l)
    ##if __name__ == '__main__':
        ##unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite) # run all tests
```

this file imports all modules starting with 'test_' in the same directory and adds them all to the `suite` variable.

`suite` should be run by pydev but I cannot test it - i do not have pydev.

Comment: Doesn't really address specifically the running in PyDev.